# Implement search bar button and file tree components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In this app I have a **search engine** that is supposed to look inside the **file tree** for desired content. The purpose is, when searching for some content and clicking the **Search button**, the file tree will filter and show what you are looking for.

For now, I have a `console.log()` (check `onSubmitSearch(e)` inside `<SearchEngine/>`) telling me what content I am asking to search when I click the Search button. The only thing missing is the search actually looking **inside the file tree**. How do I do that?

Please check the working snippet attached.

Thank you!

```js
/**** TEXT BOX COMPONENT ****/
class TextBox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { content: "Select A Node To See Its Data Structure Here..." };

    this.changeContent = this.changeContent.bind(this);
  }

  changeContent(newContent) {
    this.setState({ content: newContent });
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({
      content: nextProps.content
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="padd_top">
        <div className="content_box">
          {this.state.content}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

/**** SEARCH COMPONENT ****/
class SearchEngine extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: "" };
    
    this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmitSearch = this.onSubmitSearch.bind(this);
  }

  onInputChange(e) {
    const content = e.target.value;
    this.setState({value: content});
    console.log(content);
  }
  
  onSubmitSearch(e) { // CONSOLE LOG IS HERE
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('A node was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
       <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmitSearch}>
            <input
              className="form-control"
              value={this.state.value}
              type="text"
              onChange={this.onInputChange}
            />
            <p>{this.state.value}</p>
            <SearchButton />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

/**** SEARCH BUTTON ****/ 
class SearchButton extends React.Component {

    render() {
      return (
        <button
            type="submit"
            value="submit"
            bsStyle="danger"> Search
        </button>
      );
    }
}

/**** FILE TREE COMPONENT ****/ 
let data = [
  {
    type: "directory",
    name: ".",
    contents: [
      {
        type: "directory",
        name: "./bin",
        contents: [{ type: "file", name: "./bin/greet" }]
      },
      {
        type: "directory",
        name: "./lib",
        contents: [{ type: "file", name: "./lib/greeting.rb" }]
      },
      {
        type: "directory",
        name: "./spec",
        contents: [
          { type: "file", name: "./spec/01_greeting_spec.rb" },
          { type: "file", name: "./spec/02_cli_spec.rb" },
          { type: "file", name: "./spec/spec_helper.rb" }
        ]
      },
      { type: "file", name: "./CONTRIBUTING.md" },
      { type: "file", name: "./Gemfile" },
      { type: "file", name: "./Gemfile.lock" },
      { type: "file", name: "./LICENSE.md" },
      { type: "file", name: "./README.md" }
    ]
  }
];

// Icon file image for 'FileTree'
const FileIcon = () => {
  return (
    <div className="svg-icon">
      <svg
        id="icon-file-text2"
        className="icon"
        viewBox="0 0 32 32"
        fill="currentColor"
        width="1em"
        height="1em"
      >
        <path d="M28.681 7.159c-0.694-0.947-1.662-2.053-2.724-3.116s-2.169-2.030-3.116-2.724c-1.612-1.182-2.393-1.319-2.841-1.319h-15.5c-1.378 0-2.5 1.121-2.5 2.5v27c0 1.378 1.122 2.5 2.5 2.5h23c1.378 0 2.5-1.122 2.5-2.5v-19.5c0-0.448-0.137-1.23-1.319-2.841zM24.543 5.457c0.959 0.959 1.712 1.825 2.268 2.543h-4.811v-4.811c0.718 0.556 1.584 1.309 2.543 2.268zM28 29.5c0 0.271-0.229 0.5-0.5 0.5h-23c-0.271 0-0.5-0.229-0.5-0.5v-27c0-0.271 0.229-0.5 0.5-0.5 0 0 15.499-0 15.5 0v7c0 0.552 0.448 1 1 1h7v19.5z" />
        <path d="M23 26h-14c-0.552 0-1-0.448-1-1s0.448-1 1-1h14c0.552 0 1 0.448 1 1s-0.448 1-1 1z" />
        <path d="M23 22h-14c-0.552 0-1-0.448-1-1s0.448-1 1-1h14c0.552 0 1 0.448 1 1s-0.448 1-1 1z" />
        <path d="M23 18h-14c-0.552 0-1-0.448-1-1s0.448-1 1-1h14c0.552 0 1 0.448 1 1s-0.448 1-1 1z" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
};

// Icon folder image for 'FileTree'
 const FolderIcon = () => {
  return (
    <div className="svg-icon">
      <svg
        id="icon-folder"
        className="icon"
        viewBox="0 0 32 32"
        fill="currentColor"
        height="1em"
        width="1em"
      >
        <path d="M14 4l4 4h14v22h-32v-26z" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
};

// Icon arrow image for 'FileTree'
 const TriangleDown = () => {
  return (
    <div className="svg-icon">
      <svg
        id="svg__icon--triangle-down"
        viewBox="0 0 9 4.5"
        fill="currentColor"
        height="1em"
        width="1em"
      >
        <path d="M0,0,4.5,4.5,9,0Z" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
};

// Filters file 'name' and adds '/'
const formatName = name => {
  return name.substr(name.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
};

// Dummy data set
var root = data[0];

// Construction of FileTree
 class FileTree extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activeNode: null
    };
    this.setActiveNode = this.setActiveNode.bind(this);
  }

  setActiveNode(name) {
    this.setState({ activeNode: name });
    this.props.liftStateUp(name);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps({ searchTerm }) {
    this.setState({ searchTerm });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="padd_top">
        {renderTree(
          this.props.root || root,
          this.setActiveNode,
          this.state.activeNode,
          null,
          this.state.searchTerm
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}


/**** DIRECTORY ****/
class Directory extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { expanded: true };

    this.toggleDirectory = this.toggleDirectory.bind(this);
  }

  toggleDirectory() {
    this.setState({ expanded: !this.state.expanded });
  }

  hasMatchingNodes() {
    const searchTerm = this.props.searchTerm.toLowerCase();
    const matchNode = node =>
      node.contents
        ? node.contents.filter(matchNode).length !== 0
        : node.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) !== -1;
    return matchNode(this.props.node);
  }

  render() {
    let node = this.props.node;
    const rotate = this.state;

    if (this.props.searchTerm && !this.hasMatchingNodes()) return null;
    return (
      <div className="directory-container">
        <div className="directory">
          <div
            className={`directory__toggle ${
              this.state.expanded ? "expanded" : ""
              }`}
          >
            <div onClick={this.toggleDirectory}>
              <TriangleDown onClick={() => this.setState({ rotate: true })}
                className={rotate ? "rotate" : ""} />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="directory__icon" onClick={this.toggleDirectory}>
            <FolderIcon />
          </div>

          <div className="directory__name" onClick={this.toggleDirectory}>
            <div>{formatName(node.name)}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        {this.state.expanded
          ? node.contents.map((content, index) =>
            renderTree(
              content,
              this.props.setActiveNode,
              this.props.activeNode,
              index,
              this.props.searchTerm
            )
          )
          : ""}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Set class Active to selected file
const File = ({ name, setActiveNode, activeNode, searchTerm }) => {
  if (searchTerm && name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) < 0)
    return null;
  let isActive = activeNode === name;
  let className = isActive ? "active" : "";

  return (
    <div className={className + " file"} onClick={() => setActiveNode(name)}>
      <div className="file__icon">
        <FileIcon />
      </div>
      <div className="file__name">{formatName(name)}</div>
      {isActive && <div className="file__options">...</div>}
    </div>
  );
};

var renderTree = (node, setActiveNode, activeNode, index, searchTerm) => {
  if (node.type === "file") {
    return (
      <File
        key={index}
        name={node.name}
        setActiveNode={setActiveNode}
        activeNode={activeNode}
        searchTerm={searchTerm}
      />
    );
  } else if (node.type === "directory") {
    return (
      <Directory
        key={index}
        node={node}
        setActiveNode={setActiveNode}
        activeNode={activeNode}
        searchTerm={searchTerm}
      />
    );
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};

/**** APP ****/
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activeNode: ""
    };

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }

  liftStateUp = (data) => {
    this.setState({ activeNode: data });
  };

  onChange(data) {
    this.setState({ searchTerm: data });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="col-md-12">
          <SearchEngine className="form-control" onChange={this.onChange} />
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <FileTree
            liftStateUp={this.liftStateUp}
            searchTerm={this.state.searchTerm}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <TextBox content={this.state.activeNode}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: #333333 !important;
}

/** DIRECTORY CSS **/

.directory {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.directory__toggle {
  padding-left: 10px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg)
}

.directory__icon {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.directory__icon {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.directory__name {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.directory-container {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

/** FILE CSS **/

.file {
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  display: flex;
}

.file__icon {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.file__name {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.file__options {
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  stroke-width: 0;
  stroke: currentColor;
  fill: currentColor;
}

.svg-icon {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}

.expanded {
  transform: rotate(0deg)
}

/** CONTENT BOX **/

.padd_top {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.btn-danger {
  color: #fff !important;
}

.content_box {
  font-size: 12px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #9da5ab;
  min-height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
}

.text_color {
  color: #21252b !important;
}

/** arrow animation **/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
 <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
 <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
 <title>React App</title>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="app"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what backend are you planning/willing/considering to use? for `nodejs/express` I would recommend package `serve-index`, [link here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve-index)

Comment: It's hard to understand where the `data` array is being used. The `data` should  be filtered by the `searchTerm` that gets entered, which should happen in whatever component is passing the data to `FileTree`. I'm having a hard time finding where that is though, can you explain the flow of data a little bit more?

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda check the code inside `class Directory`, after `class FileTree`

Comment: @seethrough backend is going to be with Java, I think.

Comment: I am not proficient in that. I would advise to post a new question or even to google beforehand on how to do the file search using Java. Then you would send results to your frontend via json. And after that display. The React/Javascript part here is minimal

Comment: @seethrough for now I'm just looking for a solution for basic functionality using dummy data, but your knowlegde is very helpful for the near future.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're actually asking. Are you asking how to filter the tree based on what you're searching for?

Comment: @DaveNewton yes. For example, I want to search for "greeting.rb". I write "greeting.rb", click on the search button, and the `<FileTree/>` component will show the results by filtering to the content I'm searching. Basically, it's something like this: http://storybooks.github.io/react-treebeard/, but the only difference is the `<SearchEngine/>` component has a search button.

Comment: @RCohen Okay. So as it stands now, this will be hard, because you don't render based on props--if you passed the tree into the component you could just re-render based on the current data. It might not be the *best* approach, but React tree components I've worked with (why aren't you just using one of those?) take the tree data as a property and renders based on that.

Comment: @DaveNewton Okay. So what what you suggesting exactly? Which component you were refering to?

Comment: The one that calls the renderTree function.

Comment: @DaveNewton I think I understand your suggestion, but that solution will also require to change other pieces of code besides  the renderTree function, probably.

Comment: Yes, it will. It's similar to the accepted answer.

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks for the help. By the way, you said there is React tree components. Can you tell me which components you already used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is data propagation. You gave data to FileTree Component and your SearchEngine is on the same level as the FileTree Component, and it cannot access the data which has to be filtered. I lifted up data to App Component - parent of SearchEngine and FileTree Component and propagated data to FileTree. Instead of propagating data to SearchEngine - I lifted onSubmitSearch event handler to App Component and propagated it to SearchEngine, because even if I gave data to SearcEngine I couldn't update it on FileTree Component (because of unidirectional data flow).

```
// Dummy data set
var root = data[0];

/**** APP ****/
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activeNode: "",
      root: root
    };

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }

  liftStateUp = data => {
    this.setState({ activeNode: data });
  };

  onSubmitSearch = (e, search) => {
    let tree = JSON.stringify(root); // always search full data tree
    tree = JSON.parse(tree); // JSON.stringify and then JSON.parse are
    if (!search || search === "") {
      // if search is undefined, null or empty, set root to full data tree
      this.setState({ root: tree }); // state.root is filtered tree passed to the FileTree component
      return;
    }
    /*uncoment if you need to filter already filtered tree*/
    // tree = JSON.stringify(this.state.root);
    // tree = JSON.parse(tree);
    /**/

    // else filter tree
    this.setState({
      root: this.filterTree(tree, search.toLowerCase())
    });
  };

  filterTree = (data, search) => {
    let children = data.contents;

    if (!children || !children.length) {
      if (!data.name.toLowerCase().includes(search)) {
        data.remove = true;
      }
    } else {
      for (let i = children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        this.filterTree(children[i], search);
        if (children[i].remove) {
          children.splice(i, 1);
        }
      }
      if (!children.length) {
        data.remove = true;
      }
    }

    return data;
  };

  onChange(data) {
    this.setState({ searchTerm: data });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="col-md-12">
          <SearchEngine
            className="form-control"
            onChange={this.onChange}
            onSubmitSearch={this.onSubmitSearch}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <FileTree
            root={this.state.root}
            liftStateUp={this.liftStateUp}
            searchTerm={this.state.searchTerm}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <TextBox content={this.state.activeNode} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Note that App now has onSubmitSearch function which is then propagated to SearchEngine where it is called with the search input value:

```
/**** SEARCH COMPONENT ****/
class SearchEngine extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: "" };

    this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);
  }

  onInputChange(e) {
    const content = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ value: content });
  }

  render() {
    const { onSubmitSearch } = this.props;
    const { value } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={e => onSubmitSearch(e, value)}>
          <input
            className="form-control"
            value={this.state.value}
            type="text"
            onChange={this.onInputChange}
          />
          <p>{this.state.value}</p>
          <SearchButton />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And the FileTree Component now gets filtered data (by search input value / search engine) and takes care about rendering FileTree Component only.

Take a look at the working example of filtering tree structure with submit button here: https://codesandbox.io/s/3rnvv0kln6

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! Really helpful! @Vikky

Comment: No problem! I'm glad I could help! :)

Comment: That is @RCohen code, I don't really get why does he need   `liftStateUp = data => {
    this.setState({ activeNode: data });
  };` function...

Comment: `liftStateUp = (data) =>{
    this.setState({ activeNode: data})
  }` to pass props from `<TextBox/>` to `<App/>`
@Vikky